# Add duplicate key in Asp.net dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a scenario where I want to add duplicate key in dropdown list. Below is exsiting code-

```
 currentVersionDDL.DataSource = DDLList.ToList();
 currentVersionDDL.DataTextField = "Value";
 currentVersionDDL.DataValueField = "Key";
```

where DDLList is dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, string> DDLList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

As per new requirement, I will have to add duplicate key in dropdown, Is there any way to do this without too much changing existing code. Please suggest. I tried with `Lookup` but it is not fitting in.

Comment: Why would you want this just out of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the DataSource type to do this, because a `Dictionary` does not allow duplicated keys by an obvious reason, you could not determine which is the value associated to the key. A quick-and-dirty solution that works:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> items = DDLList.AsEnumerable().ToList();
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "Name 1");
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "Name 1");
currentVersionDDL.DataSource = items;
currentVersionDDL.DataTextField = "Value";
currentVersionDDL.DataValueField = "Key";
```

Dictionaries do not allow duplicate keys, but Lists do. With this simple solution you don't even have to change the DropDown component bound properties.